# Is there a closed form for the polygamma function?

Tags: real-analysis, closed-form, digamma-function

Mathematica gave me that
$$
\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac1{k^2} = \texttt{PolyGamma[1,n]}.
$$
However, in all my attempts to simplify and approximate the number as a decimal, it kept leaving it in terms of the "PolyGamma" function. I understand that
\begin{align}
\texttt{PolyGamma[1,1]} &= \psi^{(1)}(1) \\
&= (-1)^2 \int_0^\infty \frac{te^{-t}}{1-e^{-t}}\ \mathsf dt\\
&= \frac{\pi^2}6,
\end{align}
and in general

\begin{align}
\texttt{PolyGamma[1,n]} &= \psi^{(1)}(n)\\ &=  \int_0^\infty \frac{te^{-nt}}{1-e^{-t}}\ \mathsf dt\\ &= -\int_0^1 \frac{t^{n-1}}{1-t}\log t\ \mathsf dt.
\end{align}
Is this just not an integral that cannot be solved analytically? Wolfram Alpha gives me the series expansion
$$
\frac1{n^2} + \frac{\pi^2}6 + n \psi^{(2)}(1) + \frac{\pi^4n^2}{30} + O(n^3),
$$
which is fairly useless considering $n$ as a continuous variable, as this is the series expansion about $0$.

If this integral cannot be computed analytically, then what is a good approximation for $\texttt{PolyGamma[1,n]}$ as a function of $n$? I see that it can be computed exactly for any fixed $n$. But I am interested in the map $n\mapsto \psi^{(1)}(n)$.

Edit: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigamma_function#Computation_and_approximation) it appears that an easy way to approximate the trigamma function is to take the derivative of the series expansion of the digamma function:
$$
\psi^{(1)}(n) = \frac1n + \frac1{2x^3} + \frac1{6x^3} - \frac1{30x^5} + \frac1{42x^7} - \frac1{30x^9} + \frac5{66x^{11}} - \frac{691}{2730x^{13}} + \frac7{6x^{15}} + O(n^{17})
$$
However I see no clear pattern as to the coefficients in this Laurent series.

Comment: As for the approximation check out the [wiki.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function#Asymptotic_expansion)

Comment: Is that an asymptotic approximation (i.e. only valid for large $n$)? I am looking for an approximation for small $n$.

Comment: [$ψ^{(n)⁡}(1)=(-1)^{n+1}⁢n!⁢\,ζ⁡(n+1)$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.15). Values of $⁢ζ⁡(n+1)$ for odd $n$ are [known explicitly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Riemann_zeta_function#Even_positive_integers).

Comment: What WA gives you is the expansion around $n=0$. If you consider $n$ as a continuous variable, the result is already very poor for $n=1$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Very good observation. I suspected the series expansion was of no use anyway.

Comment: @Conifold Is there a proof that $\psi^{(n)}(1) = (-1)^{n+1}n!\xi(n+1)$? Your link just seems to state it without proof.

Comment: It follows from the [standard definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygammaFunction.html), although looking closer what you want is probably $\psi^{(1)}(n)$ rather than $\psi^{(n)}(1)$.

Comment: Hmm, I think you are correct. I will have to revise my question.

Comment: Look at [trigamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigamma_function), you can just compute the values recursively by subtracting reciprocal squares from $\frac{\pi^2}6$.

Comment: If there was an easy closed form, you would find it in every textbook.

Comment: @Conifold So $\psi^{(1)}(1) = \frac{\pi^2}6$, $\psi^{(1)}(1) = \frac{\pi^2}6-1$, $\psi^{(1)}(2) = \psi^{(1)}(3) =  \psi^{(1)}(2) -\frac14 = \frac{\pi^2}6 - \frac54$, and so on? If so this seems to be a simple recurrence for the value of $\psi^{(1)}(n)$. Could you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) gives the asymptotic approximation
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac1{k^2}
&\sim\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{B_{2k}}{n^{2k+1}}\\
&=\frac1n+\frac1{2n^2}+\frac1{6n^3}-\frac1{30n^5}+\frac1{42n^7}-\frac1{30n^9}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^{11}}\right)
\end{align}
$$
where $B_n$ are the [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number).

Note that this is an asymptotic approximation; that is, the series does not converge.

---

If you need an exact answer, then the best you can do would be
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac1{k^2}
&=\frac{\pi^2}6-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1{k^2}\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}6-H^{(2)}_{n-1}
\end{align}
$$
where $H^{(2)}_n$ are the [Generalized Harmonic Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalized_harmonic_numbers).

Comment: This is for $\psi^{(1)}(1)$. I am interested in $\psi^{(1)}(n)$ for positive integers $n$.

Comment: This *is* for positive integer $n$

Comment: Oh, I missed that the sum starts at $k=n$ instead of $k=1$. I see now, interesting.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I will accept your answer.

Comment: I have to wonder why Mathematica will only give $\texttt{PolyGamma[1,n]}$ instead of $\frac{\pi^2}6 - \texttt{HarmonicNumber[n-1,2]}$.